# HTML between two separated PHP selectors contains if statement

Tags: php, html, if-statement, rendering

```
<?php if(1 == 2){echo 1; ?>
   <div>2</div>
<?php echo 3;} ?>
```

In this code, I expected the `div` to be shown since it is just an html outside the php, but it doesn't. It works as a part of the php.

Is this a bug or it is how PHP works?

Comment: You don't terminate the `if` block until after your HTML output, what's the problem?

Comment: @Marty I expected it to treat the html part out of the php, So i `echo 1` first, then show html, then `echo 3` in case the statement is true. And only show the html in case the statment is false, But now it is like echoing the html inside the php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of what you are trying to output is going to make it to the screen.

You are "saying":

```
<?php 
if(1 == 2){
    echo 1; ?>
    <div>2</div>
    <?php echo 3;
}
?>
```

or another way to write is...

```
<?php 
if(1 == 2){
    echo 1;
    ?><div>2</div><?php
    echo 3;
}
?>
```

It is never true, so there is nothing to display.

---

Perhaps this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
if(1==2){
    echo 1;
}
echo '<div>2</div>';
if(1==2){
    echo 3;
}
// output: <div>2</div>
```

Comment: I thought that by separating the php into two parts, The html would be treated as just an `HTML` code, And not as a part of the `PHP` too.

Comment: It all renders (gets "merged" as html) as it reads the script.  The php isn't "ignored" just because the script temporarily leaves php (`?>`).

Comment: AXAI it is treated as html but inside the if statement so it will only show when the if statement is true

Answer (score 1):

It is important to remember that PHP is evaluated by the server in the order it is written, and braces tell the PHP server to evaluate the `if` as one unit, then decide what is sent (eg. HTML output).
It can be considered like below.

```
<?php 
if (true) {
    //everything in here relies on the above if statement. 
    //I can exit php to write in HTML or plain text,
    //but it remains within the same bracket
}
?>
```

This allows a few things. First, it means you can run complicated processes to decide if data should even be sent. Take the below example.

```
<?php

// Function ignored as one whole chunk until called
function check_user_login() {
    // check user login and return true for logged in or false if not
}

// If statement checked, now calls the function.
if (check_user_login()) {
    // If you are logged in, then it will evalute everything within these braces. 
    // The result includes printing what is outside the `php` tags.
    ?>
    <div>Secure information that should only be sent if the user is logged in</div>
    <?php
} // now exiting the braces, we will evaluate the rest in order

?>
<h1>My Website</h1>
```

The PHP will evaluate the statement, if it is true (you are logged in), then you get what is in the braces (the secure information), otherwise it is like it never existed.

This is one of the reasons many PHP frameworks use a template system so that you can work in a more visual structure, leaving the server evaluation part of the code sit in another file

Answer (score 0):

No that is how php works. Anything inside the brackets will be considered as within the if statement even if it is outside of the php tags.